# Use state retorna undefined

Tags: node.js, react, typescript, react-native, prisma

não entendo por que meu state não tras nada no params, mas funciona no console.log

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function loadProducts() {
        const response = await api.get('/product/category', {
            params: {
                category_id: selectedCategory?.id,
                //tamanho:  selectedSize?.name
                tamanho: "G"
            }
        })

        setProduct(response.data)
        setSelectedProduct(response.data[0])

    }
    loadProducts();
}, [selectedCategory])//ação do effect ao selecionar uma categoria
```

Não entendo que passando **tamanho:"G"** funciona perfeitamente

React Native
porém, no tamanho: **selected?.name** retorna undefined mas dentro de um console.log traz o tamanho que eu selecionar no select

no meu backend node funciona perfeitamente com insomia.

Comment: seu código está todo errado.

Comment: o que está errado?

Comment: coloca todo o código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, como tenho um effect ligado a 2 states precisava passar os dois como dependencia e não somente um.

solução

}, [selectedCategory, selectedSize])//dependencia do useEffect

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).